# Is there a twig alternative for DateTime::createFromFormat(...)?

Tags: php, date, twig

I've got a string representing the week number and year and would like to output the sunday of this week.

Example in PHP:

```
$dateString = '502016';
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('WY', $dateString);
echo $dateObject->format('Y-m-d');
```

Something like:

```
{{ published_at|format(date("Ymd"), 'd-m-Y') }}
```

Is this possible in twig?

Comment: tried to use `date` filter/function?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov How will it know that `112016` is in the format week year? I can't give in the source format.

Comment: indeed. It looks like you can't use `date` here. But I think you should rather convert `$dateString` to a format suitable for `date`. Otherwise, you'll need to write your own filter/function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that can help you : [overriding the built in twig date filter](https://akrabat.com/overriding-the-built-in-twig-date-filter/)

It's creating a new twig extension for what you want :)

PS: At then end it return a PHP DateTime

```
<?php
/*
 * Extension to provide updated date & date_modify filters along with an
 * updated date function which do not auto-convert strings of numbers to
 * a unix timestamp.
 *
 * Code within dateFilter(), modifyFilter() and dateFromString() extracted
 * from Twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php which is (c) 2009 Fabien Potencier
 * and licensed as per https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/master/LICENSE
 */
namespace My\Twig\Extension;

use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_SimpleFilter;
use Twig_SimpleFunction;
use DateTime;
use DateTimeInterface;
use DateTimeImmutable;

class DateExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_date';
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('date', [$this, 'dateFilter'],
                    ['needs_environment' => true]),
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('date_modify', [$this, 'modifyFilter'],
                    ['needs_environment' => true]),
        );
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('date', [$this, 'dateFromString'],
                    ['needs_environment' => true]),
        );
    }

    public function dateFilter($env, $date, $format = null, $timezone = null)
    {
        if (null === $format) {
            $formats = $env->getExtension('core')->getDateFormat();
            $format = $date instanceof DateInterval ? $formats[1] : $formats[0];
        }

        if ($date instanceof DateInterval) {
            return $date->format($format);
        }

        return $this->dateFromString($env, $date, $timezone)->format($format);
    }

    public function modifyFilter($env, $date, $format = null, $timezone = null)
    {
        $date = $this->dateFromString($env, $date, false);
        $date->modify($modifier);

        return $date;
    }

    public function dateFromString($env, $date, $timezone)
    {
        // determine the timezone
        if (!$timezone) {
            $defaultTimezone = $env->getExtension('core')->getTimezone();
        } elseif (!$timezone instanceof DateTimeZone) {
            $defaultTimezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
        } else {
            $defaultTimezone = $timezone;
        }

        // immutable dates
        if ($date instanceof DateTimeImmutable) {
            return false !== $timezone ? $date->setTimezone($defaultTimezone) : $date;
        }

        if ($date instanceof DateTime || $date instanceof DateTimeInterface) {
            $date = clone $date;
            if (false !== $timezone) {
                $date->setTimezone($defaultTimezone);
            }

            return $date;
        }

        $date = new DateTime($date, $defaultTimezone);
        if (false !== $timezone) {
            $date->setTimezone($defaultTimezone);
        }

        return $date;
    }
}
```

This class simply registers new date, date_modify filters and a new
 date function to replace the ones in Twig core and then is a direct
 copy of the functions twig_date_format_filter, twig_date_modify_filter
 and twig_date_converter with the functionality above removed.

I also needed to register this extension with the Twig_Environment
 using:

> `$env->addExtension(new \My\Twig\Extension\DateExtension());`

and I'm done.

> ```
> {{ "20141216"|date('jS F Y') }}
> {{ "20141216"|date('jS F Y') }}
> ```

now correctly outputs: 16th December 2014 16th December 2014

While, it's a shame I can't just
 override `twig_date_converter`, I'm glad that I can re-register the
 relevant `Twig` filters and function.

Comment: I did think of creating my own extension but was wondering if there was an existing solution.

Comment: Just don't post links as an answer, as URL's can dissapear over time